# Anyone help me to divide this column1 and column2 values. The values are in millions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Need to divide the two columns which as the values in Millions using python pandas dataframe.

`movies[new_columns]=movies[column1] / movies[column2] /* Not Working */`

Example:
After concentrate I see the columns look like below:

```
movies[new_columns]=movies[column1] + movies[column2]

0       $151.1MM$30.0MM
1     $341.27MM$150.0MM
2       $51.74MM$12.0MM
3      $100.55MM$47.0MM
4         $47.7MM$9.0MM
```

Anyone help me to divide this column1 and column2 values. The values are in millions.

Logic implemented:

```
# Divide the 'gross' and 'budget' columns by 1000000 to convert '$' to 'million $'
movies['Budget_in_($)_millions'] = '$' + (movies['budget'].astype(float)/1000000).round(2).astype(str) + 'MM'
movies
```

Kindly assist.

Thanks, SB

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you need processing floats columns:

```
movies['budget'] = movies['budget'].astype(float)/1000000)

movies['new_columns'] = movies['column1'] / movies['column2']
```

Last step convert to strings and addded prefixes, suffixes:

```
movies['Budget_in_($)_millions'] = '$' + movies['budget'].round(2).astype(str) + 'MM'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using above logic I implemented below , it works

```
mov = movies['budget'].astype(float)/1000000

movies['Budget_in_($)_millions'] = '$' + mov.round(2).astype(str) + 'MM'
```